# docker-compose.yml services.back.environment.links contains ["postgres"], which is an invalid type, it should be a string, number, or a null

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx-front:
    image: 'nginx:stable'
    ports:
      - '3000:80'
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-front.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    links:
      - front
      - back
  front:
    image: 'node:10'
    ports:
      - '3001:3000'
    environment:
      REACT_EDITOR: atom
    volumes:
      - ./front:/home/app
      - ./build.sh:/build.sh
    entrypoint: /build.sh
  back:
    image: 'node:10'
    environment:
      PGUSER: '${PG_USER}'
      PGPASSWORD: '${PG_PASSWORD}'
      PGDATABASE: '${PG_DATABASE}'
      PGHOST: postgres
      links:
        - postgres
    volumes:
    - ./back:/home/app
    - ./build.sh:/build.sh
    entrypoint: /build.sh
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:9.6'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: '${PG_DATABASE}'
      POSTGRES_USER: '${PG_USER}'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '${PG_PASSWORD}'
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
  pgweb:
    image: sosedoff/pgweb
    command: pgweb --readonly --bind=0.0.0.0 --listen=8081
    ports:
      - '5000:8081'
    links:
      - 'postgres:postgres'
    environment:
      - >-
        DATABASE_URL=postgres://${PG_USER}:${PG_PASSWORD}@postgres:5432/${PG_DATABASE}?sslmode=disable
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  volumes:
  data: {}
```

I am getting the following:

> docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml config
>   ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
>   services.back.environment.links contains ["postgres"], which is an invalid type, it should be a string, number, or a null

This is from a project I have forked on github (https://github.com/affluent-bilby-classifieds/fruty_ra-cb-menu). I intend to extend the project but first I hoped to further automate the building process. Any assistance would hugely appreciated.

The offending lines seem to be 29-30. I am just not sure how to fix it.
links:
        - postgres

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
links:
   - 'postgres'
```

to pass it as a string. Check the compose file reference https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/ for syntax rules and also some info about different versions and upgrading.

Comment: thanks user3002354. Unfortunately this hasn't fixed the issue. The file did work in it's original version before I started making changes to it. I might take it back to it's original state and try adding the hook to it from there.